# Can Visual Studio Automatically Expand Text with a Code Snippet?

Tags: visual-studio

In Delphi if I type "if" and space it automatically inserts the code snippet with an if statement block defined. I know in Visual Studio I can insert a snippet, but I have to either right-click and select "insert snippet", or hit CTRL-K followed by CTRL-X.

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio to automatically insert the snippet like Delphi does?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Press tab tab.